# Simple table without borders

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabu, tabulary

I would like to draw simple table without borders but the problem the the content of the second column exceeds the margins of document
How can I fix that problem

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{cl}
    Year 2023-2024 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
    Year 2022-2023 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text \\
    Year 2021-2022 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long   \\
    Year 2020-2021 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
    Year 2019-2020 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
    Year 2018-2019 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just replace `l` by `p{8cm}` or whatever length instead of `8cm`. Of course there are packages which compute the remaining distance for you like `tabularx` and so on.

Comment: It's works just fine

Comment: @marmot you can turn your comment into solution

Answer (score 5):

Use `tabularx` and the `X` column type. This should be fine:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c>{\arraybackslash}X}
Year 2023-2024 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
Year 2022-2023 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text \\
Year 2021-2022 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long   \\
Year 2020-2021 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
Year 2019-2020 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
Year 2018-2019 & Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text Very long very long text  \\
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Could you please add possibility to add border in case if we need it to the same table

Comment: @Bernard - I guess you don't need `\arraybackslash` here, please correct me if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @AboAmmar: You're probably right (I don't know well the details). I always add it just in case… I don't think it does any harm: it's just to ensure `\\\` for a new row has no problem.